# Forces on a spinning ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, projectile, drag, lift

The drag force opposes the direction of velocity, and the lift force is perpendicular to both the drag force and the rotation direction.

So if a tennis ball is rotating clockwise and moving to the left with velocity v, the drag force is acting to the right, and the lift force is acting downwards since for clockwise rotation the lift force acts down. Or is the lift force acting upwards since the ball is moving left and spinning clockwise?

Now let's consider the tennis ball rotating clockwise and purely moving upwards, in the positive y direction only.  The drag force is downwards, but what direction is the lift force now?  Is it to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decide the direction of lift force on a spinning ball , you should know about [magnus force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect)( and also about the **Bernoulli's Principle** linked in dnaik's answer )
which says that if kinetic energy of the moving fluid at a **certain fixed height $h$** is  increased then the pressure of the fluid decreases.

[image: see this animation],

---

When the tennis ball is rotating clockwise and moving with velocity $v$ in the left direction , the air will be flowing towards the right direction with respect to the ball and since it is rotating clockwise, the air above the ball will have more velocity than the air below the ball. Due to this the kinetic energy of the air above is more and so air pressure is less than the pressure of the air below the ball. Due to this pressure difference, a net force acts on the ball in the upward direction (shown by yellow arrow in the gif) and that can prevent the ball from falling down due to gravity.

---

Same process can be applied during upward motion.

---

When the ball is thrown upward and also rotating clockwise , the air is coming down with respect to the ball and because of the spin there exists a pressure difference and hence the ball experiences a force in the right direction.

---

**Note** : To visualise the direction of magnus force in the case of upward motion  , look at the same animation by rotating your screen (if possible otherwise just imagine the image to be rotated in clockwise direction) by $90°$.

---

Hope it helps ☺️.

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind the lift force is the [Bernoulli's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle). As the direction of life depends both on the direction of rotation, and the direction of the ball itself.

When a ball rotating clockwise is moving towards the left, the air above the ball is faster than the air below the ball, leading to lower pressure above the ball. Thus, it experiences upward lift.

When the ball is moving upwards, the air to the right is faster, thus the 'lift' force is now towards the right.